# How do I generate script for LocalDB database?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, localdb

I'm using localdb for development with Visual Studio and SSDT. I want to export the database schema and import it in full-fledged SQL Server instance. How do I do that?

I don't have (or want to install) SSMS. Can this be done with Visual Studio/SSDT only?

Comment: If SSDT implies SSIS then yes. Create a data flow task and select source and destination components (OLEDB connector) and it should help.

Comment: @PrabhatG I don't think SSDT comes with SSIS tools...

Answer (score 4):

In SSDT, just do a schema compare against a blank database and it will build a change script for you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I'll summarize the answers and give a bit more suggestions.

**Use schema compare**

As @Nick.McDermaid mentioned you can use schema compare to generate the script. However if you use variables it might not work as you expected. Moreover pre/post scripts will not be included to the output script

**Use SSDT Publish**

Right-click on the project and choose Publish. There setup the connection and you will have 2 options.

- Publish
- Generate script

Choose the one you need

**Dacpac**

You can build the project and find the project_name.dacpac file in the bin folder. Then you can use SqlPackage to deploy your changes ([HOWTO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080(v=vs.103).aspx))

Answer (score 0):

Just publish the SSDT project to another SQL Server instance/edition